What happens if I move an object that has Darkness cast on it?
In the 2014 rules, the Darkness spell said the following:

Magical darkness spreads from a point you choose within range to fill a 15-foot radius sphere for the duration...
If the point you choose is on an object you are holding or one that isn’t being worn or carried, the darkness emanates from the object and moves with it. Completely covering the source of the darkness with an opaque object, such as a bowl or a helm, blocks the darkness.

I took this to mean that you could cast the spell on a pebble in your hand and then toss that around the battlefield as a way to mobilize the spell.
In the 2024 rules, the Darkness spell is a bit more restricted saying:

magical Darkness spreads from a point within range and fills a 15-foot-radius Sphere...
you cast the spell on an object that isn’t being worn or carried, causing the Darkness to fill a 15-foot Emanation originating from that object. Covering that object with something opaque, such as a bowl or helm, blocks the Darkness.

The new version omits the option to target an object you're holding and doesn't say whether the darkness moves with the object.
Does this mean that the spell can no longer be moved once cast? It seems like such an intent could have been achieved by simply stating that the caster chooses a point from where the spell originates and left it there. The inclusion of being able to target an object suggests that shenanigans are acceptable.
One thought I'd had on this is that the intent for it being able to target objects you're not carrying is that it makes it far more difficult for characters who lack a means to see through magical darkness to pick up the object and throw it. So the combo is readily available to Devil Sight Warlocks and Shadow Monks per the time-limited object interactions, but not any random wizard who would be subject to the rules for finding hidden objects, since they can just cast the spell on something on the floor then pick it up and move it.
However, this interpretation might run afoul of the general mantra of spells only doing what they say they do. I'm unclear how firm that rule is in the 2024 rules.
So what happens if I throw a pebble that has Darkness cast on it?

Isn't that part of "Emanation" definition?

Are you actually asking for comparison of how the spell works between editions, or just how the spell works in 2024? We only need the tag for 2014 if you’re actually asking for a comparative analysis. If all you’re really asking for is how it works in 2024, the 2014 tag isn’t necessary, even though the 2014 example is given.

@ThomasMarkov I kind of overthought myself when adding the tags because of how much I was referencing the previous edition.

"Emanation" is a separately defined term in the 2024 spell rules, but wasn't in 2014, so the 2024 spell wording doesn't need to say as much.

Wondering about the intent of the "object that isn’t being worn or carried" clause: it's probably so that you cannot cast Darkness on an object worn by an enemy, making it impossible or very inconvenient for them to escape the darkness. So it's fine to cast Darkness on an object on the floor and to pick it up to move it. But it's not possible to cast it on the armor of an enemy.

An Emanation moves with its origin.
You'll note that the rules you cited refer to the darkness as filling an Emanation.

you cast the spell on an object that isn’t being worn or carried, causing the Darkness to fill a 15-foot Emanation originating from that object.

An Emanation, among other things, moves with its origin.

An Emanation moves with the creature or object that is its origin unless it is an instantaneous or a stationary effect.

Therefore, Darkness still works the way you would expect it to when cast on an object; the darkness moves with the object.
While you could cast Darkness as a stationary effect on "a point within range", often it will be preferable to cast it on an object and interact with it through free object Interactions.

Tongue piercing warlock here I come!

@order I see light and darkness (although from older versions, they seem unchanged in the object aspect) most commonly cast on "this random pebble/rock there", which is then thrown, picked up and carried around, or even just repeatedly kicked ahead of the party.

If the target of Darkness is no longer a valid target (it is no longer an object for example, or becomes worn or carried) what basis do you have that the effect continues?

@Yakk, Any point is a valid target, that point needn't be on an object.

@Yakk, The effect continues because it is part of the duration of a concentration spell. The object not being worn or carried is a restriction of the casting, but not on the duration. Unless, is there some basis to believe that picking up an object would interrupt concentration or negate a level 2 spell?

@nonymous So, you cast it on an object,  It is then animated.  "causing the Darkness to fill a 15-foot Emanation originating from that object." - does darkness end, because there is no object for the Emanation to Emanate from? Does the qualification "object that isn’t being worn or carried, causing the Darkness to fill a 15-foot Emanation originating from that object." suddenly end? If it was "metal object" and the object was converted to stone, would heat metal still deal damage as the word "metal" was only mentioned when the spell was cast on it? It isn't nearly as simple as you make it out.

@Yakk, RAW, Heat Metal doesn't end because its target is e.g. petrified. Maybe that's a bad rule that a good DM should overrule. You can wax pedantic over whether that "worn or carried" clause is a prerequisite for casting versus duration. Regardless, I think it's pretty clear that both the spirit and the letter of Darkness say that you can pick up the origin of the emanation.
